# Merge 2 date datasets

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, posixct, posixlt

Reproductible code

```
library("zoo")  
library("xts")
x <- structure(c("2012-09-27 09:08:37", "2012-09-29 10:06:33", "2012-10-01 09:44:36","2012-10-04 14:37:05", "2012-10-15 13:18:21", "2012-10-17 17:33:46","2012-10-18 11:52:13", "2016-10-06 15:11:01", "2016-10-07 13:00:09","2016-10-07 12:20:57"), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", index = structure(c(1348704000,1348876800, 1349049600, 1349308800, 1350259200, 1350432000, 1350518400,1475712000, 1475798400, 1475798400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L,1L)) 
y <- structure(c("1961-08-04 10:00:00", "1971-01-01 11:00:00", "1978-01-01 11:00:00","1979-01-01 11:00:00", "1983-01-01 11:00:00", "1984-01-01 11:00:00","1985-01-01 11:00:00", "2016-10-07 20:28:24", "2016-10-07 18:27:54","2016-10-08 00:38:40"), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", index = structure(c(-265420800,31536000, 252460800, 283996800, 410227200, 441763200, 473385600,1475798400, 1475798400, 1475884800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L,1L)) 
x+y
#expected result
#  get results
#what happens
#Error in `+.default`(x, y) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Basically, i have 2 dates that i want to multiply, so that i will see just the ones that are intersecting.

**You can find the code in this gist** https://gist.github.com/baditaflorin/46b35b3044f69ed329e4c44067b7b246

Now the tclass is **Date**, i had imported the data from a csv file using

```
x <- xts(csv_file, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",order.by=as.Date(csv_file))
```

I also tried to convert the data but got error

```
x2 <- as.Date.POSIXlt( x , format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" , tz = "GMT") 

Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz, ...) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
```

These are my session informations:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8         LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
[6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8           LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C                       LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

 attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.12.0 xts_0.9-7       zoo_1.7-13     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.2.1      R6_2.2.0        tools_3.3.1     withr_1.0.2     curl_2.1        memoise_1.0.0   grid_3.3.1      digest_0.6.10  
[9] lattice_0.20-34
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (in your question please, not in a gist)? Also, the code in your gist has a syntax error (the `b <- structure...` line is not complete). The error you have stated in your question title does not match anything in your question. What does it mean to add a date?

Comment: use `dput()` on a subset of `x` to show us what's going on please. Without some info on `x`, we can only guess.

Comment: I modified the gist to include the correct code for b. @mathematical.coffee i am trying to emulate this [https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/manipulating-time-series-data-in-r-with-xts-zoo/first-order-of-business-basic-manipulations?ex=12] , but with my dataset, not the xample dataset

Comment: You have character vectors of datetimes indexed by date. For none of these types does multiplying or adding make sense. If you just want to parse to datetime, `as.POSIXct(coredata(x), tz = 'GMT')`

Comment: @alistaire thanks, this works. But when i want to calculate, i still get a error xx <- as.POSIXct(coredata(x), tz = 'GMT')
> yy <- as.POSIXct(coredata(y), tz = 'GMT')
> xx+yy
Error in `+.POSIXt`(xx, yy) : 
  binary '+' is not defined for "POSIXt" objects

Comment: Can you do formating in comments ?

Comment: Right, because that makes no sense. What is 2012-09-27 09:08:37 + 1961-08-04 10:00:00 supposed to give? A datetime in 3974? That's a useless operation, and thus no method has been written for it in R. You could write your own, if you like.

Comment: @BaditaFlorin please update your question to clarify what you are trying to do (it still is not clear), and move the code from the gist to the question (many people will not bother to click through to the link, so will not help you).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: I want to compare 2 datasets and see the dates that are in the first and second database. the same as they are doing here https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/manipulating-time-series-data-in-r-with-xts-zoo/first-order-of-business-basic-manipulations?ex=12 
Maybe there are other ways of doing it, but i don`t know, so i am trying to do it with what i know, meaning xts ( just a little, i am still a noob) @mathematical.coffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments you want either an intersection or an inner join on the index columns of the two xts-objects.

```
> intersect( index(x), index(y) )
[1] 17081
> as.Date( intersect( index(x), index(y) ) )
[1] "2016-10-07"
```

The merge in xts defaults to "outer" which is unlike the base R merge functions, so adding a "join" specification is needed:

```
> merge(x,y, join="inner")
           x                     y                    
2016-10-07 "2016-10-07 13:00:09" "2016-10-07 20:28:24"
2016-10-07 "2016-10-07 12:20:57" "2016-10-07 18:27:54"
```

Comment: thanks, it worked the first time, now is not working anymore, i tryied the last one, with merge and i get this error 4996    2013-10-24 11:05:04 2016-10-07 20:28:24
4997    2013-10-23 18:11:03 2016-10-07 20:28:24
4998    2013-10-23 09:16:10 2016-10-07 20:28:24
4999    2013-10-16 12:47:09 2016-10-07 20:28:24
5000    2013-10-16 11:55:17 2016-10-07 20:28:24
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 4608424 rows ]

From what i see it is doing everything with everything

Comment: After clearing all objects from workspace. I will stop trying and do some more tutorials, maybe there is a better way